# Didn't tapped on textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I create programmatically custom textfield

```
import UIKit

class SearchTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 5);

init(frame: CGRect, tintText: String, tintFont: UIFont, tintTextColor: UIColor) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.frame = frame

    delegate = self
    backgroundColor = .white
    textColor = tintTextColor
    placeholder = tintText
    font = tintFont

    createBorder()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    delegate = self
}

func createBorder() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 169/255, green: 169/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
}

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}
}
```

and add it like a subview to my view which is a subview of Google maps view

```
    import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

var customSearchBar: SearchTextField!
let searchBarTextColor = UIColor(red: 206, green: 206, blue: 206, alpha: 1)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 55.75, longitude: 37.62, zoom: 13.0)
    mapView.camera = camera
    mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    addTopBarView(mapView: mapView)
}



func addTopBarView(mapView: GMSMapView) {
    //heigt of topBar is 14% of height of view^ width is the same
    let topBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.14)
    let topBarView = UIView(frame: topBarFrame)
    addTopBarViewBackground(view: topBarView)
    addTitleForTopBarView(view: topBarView)
    addProfileIconForTopBarView(view: topBarView)
    addSettingsIconForTopBarView(view: topBarView)
    addSearchBar(view: topBarView)

    topBarView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mapView.addSubview(topBarView)
}


func addSearchBar(view: UIView) {
    let frameCustomSearchBar = CGRect(x: 10, y: 45, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: 40)
    let fontCustomSearchBar = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeueCyr", size: 28) ?? UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    let textColorCustomSearchBar = UIColor(red: 206/255, green: 206/255, blue: 206/255, alpha: 1)

    customSearchBar = SearchTextField(frame: frameCustomSearchBar, tintText: NSLocalizedString("find_petrole", comment: ""), tintFont: fontCustomSearchBar, tintTextColor: textColorCustomSearchBar)
    customSearchBar.delegate = self
    customSearchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    customSearchBar.isEnabled = true

    let iconPinView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_pin"))
    iconPinView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 12, height: 20)
    customSearchBar.addSubview(iconPinView)

    let iconAddView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_add"))
    iconAddView.frame = CGRect(x: customSearchBar.frame.width - 34, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
    customSearchBar.addSubview(iconAddView)

    view.addSubview(customSearchBar)
}
```

The textfield(customSearchBar) i see but it doesn't clickable, when i tapped on it nothing happens. I saw a few such problems here but did not find anything that help me.

Comment: Try to add it to the mapView. Probably touch event is hidden under map view frame

Comment: I think you should  add topBarView like this self.view.addSubview(topBarView)

Comment: @AhmedGinani Thanks a lot, it is resolved my problem

Comment: @sergs Welcome Mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need inspect UIView Hierarchy using View Debugging feature of xcode and you need to check that textfield does not overlap with other view.**

Run the app. View Debugging works in the simulator and on devices, but it's important to note that it needs to be an iOS 8 simulator or device. That said, you may allow earlier deployment targets in your project, just make sure you run on iOS 8 when you try View Debugging.
Navigate to the screen/view that you want to inspect within the running app.

In the Navigators Panel (left column), select the Debug Navigator (sixth tab). Next to your process, you'll see two buttons – press the rightmost button and select View UI Hierarchy

Comment: thanks, now i see that other view overlap the textfield http://joxi.ru/Vm6bzpgsDKxOEm Can i resolve this issue in some way?

Comment: your answer helps me to understand the issue and @AhmedGinani help to resolve it. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you put the UITextField under other touchable views so the touch event was intercepted.

if you make the custom textField hierarchy by a non-defalut `isUserInteractionEnabled` object, remember to enable it.